# SwiftUI spacer works only to half of screen in ios14

Tags: swift, swiftui

```swift
struct RootView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           Text("upper")
            
           Spacer()
        
           Text("bottom")
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly on ios16:

[image]

On ios14, however, it looks different, with me seeing the text rise from the bottom to the middle in about half a second when the app starts. What could it be?

[image]

Comment: iOS14 problem....

Comment: and putting `frame(maxHeight: .infinitiy)` under `VStack` doesn't help?

Comment: @rapiddevice nope